# "В бешеном ритме" - как выразить это в более мягкой форме?

Tags: лексика, стилистика, выбор-слов

**Большинство людей живут в бешеном ритме.**

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Большинство людей живут в скоростном ритме.** (Быстрый, ускоренный, напряженный - это еще далеко не предельные значения, бешеному ритму они не соответствуют).

Answer (score 1):

Большинство людей живут в запредельно/невероятно/очень быстром/ускоренном/напряженном ритме.

Answer (score 1):

*Бешеный ритм — помягче*? Возможно, что-то из этого подойдет:

неудержимый, отчаянный, безудержный, кипучий, бурный, неистовый, стремительный, стрессовый, интенсивный, форсированный, неослабевающий, убыстренный, невыносимый, активный, бойкий, лихорадочный.

Answer (score 1):

Большинство людей живут в сумасшедшем ритме.